# Area of polygon formed by Euclidean TSP

Tags: probability, geometry

Define $A(n)$ as the average area enclosed by the path that is the solution to a Euclidean TSP with $n$ points distributed randomly in the unit square.

*eg* For $2000$ points, $A(n)$= area of black region:

[image]

```
nn = 2000; aa = RandomReal[1, {nn, 2}];
poly = Polygon[aa[[Last[FindShortestTour[aa]]]]];
Area[poly]
Graphics[poly]
```

[It is known](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SquareTrianglePicking.html) that $A(3)=11/144$, and I assume $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}A(n)=1/2$.

Experiments with $10^5$ samples for each $n$ have yielded the following dataset:

```
data={{3,0.07639},{4,0.14744},{5,0.20324},{6,0.2458},{7,0.27886},{8,0.30435},{9,0.32526},{10,0.34206},{11,0.3564},{12,0.36824},{13,0.37809},{14,0.38694},{15,0.39419},{16,0.40115},{17,0.40695},{18,0.41292},{19,0.41743},{20,0.42135},{21,0.42558},{22,0.42932},{23,0.4327},{24,0.43606},{25,0.43874},{26,0.44156}};
```

Is it possible to solve this problem analytically for $n> 3$?

Comment: Where to the nested integrals come into play?

Comment: How do you relate Square Triangle Picking and TSP?